# How to convert the client based file path to the server based when we create symlink within NFS Drive?

Tags: c++, linux, nfs

I am developing NFS Server modules(ProcedureSYMLINK) and met path conversion issue when creating symlink.
After I run the NFS server service, I connected the server and mount as a drive on Linux Client.
And run the below command to create symbolic link within NFS Drive using full path and debug it on server side. But the target file path is not given on server path based.

ln -s /mnt/nfs/1.bin /mnt/nfs/symlink/1.lnk

Let me give you an example to clarify my question.

The base directory path on NFS Server is /usr/nfs.

So I executed below command on the Server.

./nfs_server /usr/nfs

And I mounted the NFS on Ubuntu Client using the below command.

sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.37:/usr/nfs /mnt/nfs

After that, I created the symbolic link.

ln -s /mnt/nfs/1.bin /mnt/nfs/symlink/1.lnk

/mnt/nfs/1.bin : Target Path

/mnt/nfs/symlink/1.lnk : Symlink Path

Once I enter above command and tried to debug on the server side.

in the ProcedureSYMLINK function I could see the status of variables.
I could safely get the Symlink Path which is based on Server, but the target path is not based on Server.
Target path was still /mnt/nfs/1.bin

Actually, there is no way to get the mount base path of the NFS client (/mnt/nfs) on Server.. right?
If I know the base path(/mnt/nfs), I can calculate the target file path on Server based, but I don't know the base path of the Client.

target file path may be /usr/nfs/1.bin. but no way to calculate the path like this.
Does anyone know?

I am using NFS v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points which hopefully will help answer your questions:

1. In NFS, symlinks are always resolved by the client. From the perspective of the NFS server, a symlink is just a special type of file but the content (as in, where the symlink points to) is just considered an opaque blob.
2. The mountpoint on the client (`/mnt/nfs` in your example) is purely a client-side matter, there is no provision in the NFS protocol for letting the server know it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me ask another question about relative path then.
user@raspberry:/mnt/nfs/New $ ln -s ./1.txt /mnt/nfs/1.sym
In the server, I can get symlink path: /usr/nfs/1.sym
But target path is given : ./1.txt

I just described about Linux Server, but actually, I am using Windows Server and CreateSymbolicLinkA function.
2nd parameter of the function is Target path.
In this case, I don't need to calculate absolute path on the Server?
Can I pass the 2nd argument as "./1.txt" simply?

Comment: In other word, symlink accepts any target path and it does not care to check the existence?

Comment: Why do you think that symlink is just a special type of directory entry?

Comment: @DotNetStarA: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Windows API. At least in POSIX, the symlink() function doesn't care about the contents of the target argument, and you can e.g. create symlinks pointing to a non-existent target (a so-called dangling symlink).

Comment: I mean that a symlink is a special type of file, as opposed to a regular file. See e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html for discussion on file types.

Comment: You are correct!!!! symlinks can point non-existent target. I solved the issue with aid of your help.